# Nest can't resolve dependencies of guard wrapped inside a decorator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm trying to inject a provider inside a guard that is wrapped in a decorator, but Nest is not being able to resolve dependencies, giving me the next error:

```
[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SecuredGuard (Reflector, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [1] is available in the SecuredGuard context.
```

The main purpose of my approach is to avoid using two separate decorators like this:

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  @Secured('admin')
  @UseGuards(SecuredGuard)
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

}
```

And instead insert the `@UseGuards(SecuredGuard)` inside my custom decorator `@Secured('admin')` so it ends up like this:

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  @Secured('admin')
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

}
```

This is how I'm implementing my custom decorator:

```js
export function Secured(...roles: string[]){ 

    const setMetadata = ReflectMetadata('roles', roles)
    const setupGuard = UseGuards(SecuredGuard)

    return (target: any, key?: string, descriptor?: any) => {
        setMetadata(target, key, descriptor);
        setupGuard(target, key, descriptor);
    }

}
```

And this is my `SecuredGuard`, the `AuthService` is the dependency that couldn't be resolved:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SecuredGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private readonly _reflector: Reflector,
    private readonly _authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {...}
}
```

Both `secured.guard.ts` and `secured.decorator.ts` are part of `secured.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        SecuredGuard,
        AuthModule
    ],
    exports: [
        SecuredGuard
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService
    ]
})
export class SecuredModule {}
```

Which is using the `AuthService` being exported from `auth.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  controllers: [
    AuthController
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ],
  imports: [
    EmailModule
  ],
  exports: [
    AuthService
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

And `secured.module.ts` is being imported by `app.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    SecuredModule
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't know if I'm using the appropriate approach, or even if it's possible what I'm trying to do, any clues would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, your solution seems to work, see this running example:

[image: Edit custom-decorator-injection]

---

However, there are some mistakes in your module declarations:

1) In your `AppModule`, the `AuthService` is not available, since neither is the `AuthModule` imported directly or exported by the `SecuredModule`. That's why you're getting the error.

2) You don't have to declare your guards in any module, they will just be available globally. Only put modules in your `imports` array.

3) You're providing the `AuthService` multiple times, so you will have different instances of it. You should only provide it once and then only `export` (or re-export) your provider, but not provide it again.

4) `ReflectMetadata` was deprecated in v6; use `SetMetadata` instead.

Comment: Thanks Kim! What a quick answer! That was all the thing, it's completely working now 